# About local coordinate systems and the complete description of a manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm a physics student and most of the mathematics that I think I know I learned self-taught. That said, I have the following question that may be very naive but I don't know where to really ask.

If I have a manifold gifted with the metric,
$$ ds^2 = d^2 r + d^2 \varphi$$
which comes from a larger manifold that has spherical symmetry.
I know that locally a manifold is isomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so, I can configure a Cartesian coordinate system with axes $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that to describe points far from the established origin You can apply a limit by parameterizing $x_1$, $x_2$ using:
$x_1 = r \cos \varphi$, $x_2 = r \sin \varphi$
and recover spherical symmetry? or is it something that cannot be done because I am starting from a local property?

Comment: In mathematical English "variety" usually refers to an algebraic variety (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety) and never to a manifold. The use of the term "variety" to refer to manifolds comes from mathematical French, I think.

Comment: Anyway, your question is not very clear to me, because you haven't said anything about what $r$ or $\varphi$ are. Are these spherical coordinates? Is your manifold a sphere?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I actually said write "manifold". I just corrected it. The manifold is not a sphere, I'm just talking about a general manifold that has said metric.

Comment: That expression doesn't make sense on a general manifold until you say something about what $r$ and $\varphi$ are.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the comment. I will update the question with more details

Comment: First, you mean $dr^2+d\varphi^2$. So you’re saying you have a $2$-dimensional manifold that is flat (i.e., locally isometric to a plane). I don’t see how you expect to infer anything global from just this.